# Releasing object which is not allocated without any error

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I've found that in my code i release object which had never been allocated and i do not get any error. The app doesn't crash. Everything works. I use Product -> Analyze and it tells me everything is all right.

I used to think releasing not allocated object leads to app crash. So my question is - should program crash when not allocated object is released (i.e I've missed something essential in my code which results in such a behavior) or everything runs as it is supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on if the pointer to the "unallocated" object is `nil`. In Objective-C, a message sent to `nil` does nothing. The app crash is caused by sending a message to a *dangling* pointer (or a garbage pointer etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't allocated the memory for your object, your object points to nil. When you call

```
[myobj release]
```

you're really sending the message to release to a nil object. Obj-C doesn't do anything in that case, and that's why your app doesn't crash.